# Use live media stream as participant voice instead of getUserMedia: Twilio Video

Tags: javascript, twilio, mediastream, twilio-video, videocall

I want to add a hidden participant in a group video call to play song stream as participant's voice(without video), with some control like whenever we want to stop or start, we can. I'm trying to pass media stream from a URL as **tracks** while making a connect request to join room. I'm using [quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) example for this task:

```
try {
      // Fetch an AccessToken to join the Room.
      const response = await fetch(`/token?identity=${identity}`);

      // Extract the AccessToken from the Response.
      const token = await response.text();

      // Add the specified Room name to ConnectOptions.
      connectOptions.name = roomName;

      const audio = new Audio("http://mediaserv30.live-streams.nl:8086/live");
      const ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      const stream_dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
      const source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      source.connect(stream_dest);

      const stream = stream_dest.stream;

      console.log("==================", stream.getAudioTracks());
      
      const tracks = stream.getTracks().map(track => track.kind === 'audio' ? new LocalAudioTrack(track) : new LocalVideoTrack(track));

      connectOptions.tracks = tracks;
      
      await joinRoom(token, connectOptions);
}
```

Here is what I'm getting after running this:

[image: Output]

Any help is really appreciated. I'm stuck on this problem from few days.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your code looks correct to me. And the error message in the screenshot doesn't have anything to do with what you have written.

The suggestion in the screenshot is that you are perhaps not running the application in a secure context. In order to use WebRTC you need to do so from either `localhost` or a site served over HTTPS. Are you testing this on a development domain over HTTP or using a local IP address?

If you are testing this on `localhost` then perhaps there is another issue. Please share any error logs from the developer tools that may be relevant too.